# VScode Haskell Go To Definition doesn't work for some symbols

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell-language-server

I'm getting started with Haskell and VSCode. I've forked and downloaded a [repo](https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program) with Haskell code. I've followed instructions for setting up a `nix-shell` correctly for this repo. I can successfully invoke `cabal build` and `haskell-language-server` for week 1 examples.

I've started up VSCode from within `nix-shell` and I can see that the language server is reporting symbol information to VSCode. For example:

[image]

However, I often find that if I try to `Go To Definition` VSCode reports that no definition is found:

[image]

For many of these symbols I find that if I hover my cursor over the symbol I'm shown where the symbol is defined:

[image]

Othertimes, I find that Go To Definition correctly resolves. For example, `AuctionSchema` on [this line](https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week01/src/Week01/EnglishAuction.hs#L339) resolves correctly, while `AuctionSchema` on [this line](https://github.com/paymog/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week01/src/Week01/EnglishAuction.hs#L346) does not.

Why does `Go To Definition` only sometimes work? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've same problem, I think it's a vscode bug because as you said, only sometimes work. Try to check the Output console > Tasks > Haskell <folder>, there is a log with all details.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug with the HLS: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/708

Comment: I can't get Go To Definition to even work on functions defined in the same file. HLS seems quite broken in this regard. Are there other extensions that actually work?

Comment: A bit off-topic: Can I ask what is the theme you use? Looks gorgeous!

Comment: Hah yup, it's solarized light. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanolsonx.solarized

Answer (score 2):

I use `emacs` within `NixOS`, and I find that definitions are only found when they’re within the project I’m working on. Sometimes if I’m in `src` and the definition is in `lib` it won’t find it either. I just assumed that Haskell Language Server cannot use Cabal or Hpack to find definitions, but only follows types within the directory branch the current source resides. Yep, that’s annoying, but it seems to be what’s currently on offer.

Comment: Yup, looks like it's an HLS bug: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/708